# Dom parsing in android

Tags: android

i have parsed xml using dom parser,but when the xml element contains no value it throws null pointer Exception.how to check this?...
here my code

```
NodeList TrackName1 = fstElmnt2.getElementsByTagName("Artist_Name");    


                    Element TrackElement1 = (Element) TrackName1.item(0);

                    TrackName1 = TrackElement1.getChildNodes();
                     result=result+((Node) TrackName1.item(0)).getNodeValue()

                     String  Artistname=((Node)TrackName1.item(0)).getNodeValue();



                                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for null before you try to use the value?

```
Object value = ((Node) TrackName1.item(0)).getNodeValue();
if (value != null) {
   result = result + value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

                        description = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);


                description[i] = new TextView(this);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                NodeList dataList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element dataElement = (Element) dataList.item(0);
                dataList = dataElement.getChildNodes();
                description[i].setText( ((Node) dataList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
```